# Deploy previous version in AWS Codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline

I am new to AWS and trying to create a pipeline for CICD. Stages involved in my pipeline are:

1. Source -> Codecommit
2. Build -> Codebuild project
3. Deploy using Cloudformation

I am able to complete the pipeline and deployment is successful. But I am struggling to implement a rollback procedure with this. How to deploy previous version without making a code revert in the repository? Any help regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is currently no rollback step for CodePipeline, traditionally people would rollback by reverting the change from their master branch (which is meant to represent the state of live).

If you're unable to do this revert, then you will need to manage the rollback either from a different service or different pipeline.

As you're using CloudFormation you could take a look at implementing [Rollback Triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-rollback-triggers.html) which would monitor the status of an alarm. If the alarm fails then it could rollback and fail the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks Chris for the answer. My understanding is that rollback triggers would rollback to previous successful version. What if I want to launch a version from 10 commit back?

Comment: It will rollback to the previous successful CloudFormation rollout for that stack, anything else will require a different process I am afraid.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the pipeline configuration a bit and now I am able to deploy any version from history. Below is the solution:

1. Source -> Codecommit
2. Build -> Codebuild project
3. Deploy using CodeDeploy instead of Cloudformation

Now, deployment history can be triggered at any time. Pick the version from the history in the deployments under code deploy and retry deployment.

Comment: Hi, do you have any documentation on how you did step3? "CodeDeploy instead of Cloudformation"